# Android small screen size issue

Tags: android, layout

I will get straight to the point. I have my application finished and I am trying to get the layout to work on different screen sizes. My problem is with a small screen size, say 3.7" or 4". I have a layout-small,layout,layout-large, and layout-xlarge folders with different layouts for each. For Nexus 4,5, and 6, the small layout is associated with them, when I want "layout" as I used a bigger phone for those layouts.

I wanted to use the layout-small folder for Nexus One and Nexus S, as those are smaller phone and I used those emulators for the layout. For whatever reason, when I use a small phone like the Nexus One, the layout extends beyond the page while being associated with the layout-small folder, while when using the nexus 4 or 5 phone, the layout looks fine, while being associated with layout-small. It seems like Nexus One,S,4,5,6 are being shown as associated with layout-small, but are actually using layout. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I should add that I tried doing layout-small,layout-normal,layout-large,and layout-xlarge, but everything that was associated with layout-small turned to layout-normal, and layout-small was completely dropped

Answer (score 1):

Start with http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html You should also consider the orientation as a qualifier. The "small", "normal", "large", etc is not exact and you need to find out which it is for each device (emulator) you are testing with. Just as a test, create the folder structure with all qalifiers and have a single layout in each with a single text view that is hard coded with the resource path.

Example

res/layout-small-land/test.xml android:text="layout-small-land"

res/layout-small-port/test.xml android:text="layout-small-port"

res/layout-normal-land/test.xml android:text="layout-normal-land"

res/layout-normal-port/test.xml android:text="layout-normal-port"